# How to automatically capture an authorized order in PAYPAL API using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

(Unfortunately, after a long research I could not find the answer for my question in stackoverflow).

I am currently integrating the PAYPAL REST API V2 in an e-commerce application and in principle it works fine, but not the way it is supposed to.

According to the documentation I am using the following steps:

1. Create order with user data and purchase details in the backend (nodejs)
2. Upon successful order creation, the front-end receives the approve_url and capture_url
3. The user is redirected to the approve_url and login with its credentials, and in case it is successful, the user is redirected to the predefined return_url (which is defined in the step 1)
4. If the user agrees with the order, the capture_url is manually called at the end of the checkout and the corresponding amount is transferred.

Since the data returned by the order is not persistent (url is being redirected), I am saving the order id and the capture_link in the local storage, which I don't think it is correct. Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Upon successful approval of the purchase, is it possible to redirect the user directly to capture?
2. If not, how can I get the order_id details in the return_url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the order Id was being appended to the return_url automatically. The misleading thing was that it was named token instead of order. With the order already approved by the user, I was able to complete the transaction without having to redirect the user again to the front-end.